# Get all records that matches specific column value Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I'm trying to get all records from a database table that matches the restaurant_id with a set variable. I got an old code that works, but it gets ALL the records, and not only picking the ones that matches.

```
$records = DB::table('bookings')->get()->sortBy('booking_time')->toArray();
```

This is the code I have had working with getting ALL records, but something seems to go wrong when I type this:

```
$records = DB::table('bookings')->where('restaurant_id', $restaurantId)->get();
```

I've got no error for some reason.

This is what I've got, and it does not work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you add the error that appears

Comment: Hello, I added that I don't get any errors

Comment: the query is right, there is no problems in it, are you sure there are records have the same restaurant id that you are passing?

Comment: try dd(restaurantId) can you get some id? and what id it is

Comment: I tried printing the restaurantId, and it printed [4], and not only 4. I think this may be what's causing the issue without any error

Comment: use whereIn[('restaurant_id', $restaurantId)]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this.
if you have set of restorent_id array, try as given as under.

```
$restaurantId =    [1, 2, 3];
$records = DB::table('bookings')->whereIn('your_column_name', $restaurantId )->get();
```

if you have one restaurantId ,try as given as under.

```
$records = DB::table('bookings')->where('your_column_name', $restaurantId)->get();
```